# Execute a job in SQL Server Agent : login from an untrusted domain

Tags: sql-server, ssis, active-directory, windows-authentication

I have an issue with the execution of an SSIS Package within the SQL Server Agent.

Context :

- I deployed a package into the Integrated Services Catalog : https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9Y9c.png I have not difficult to execute this package manually.

Problem :

- When I try to execute this package within a job into the SQL Server Agent, I have an error : "Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication."

  > Exécuté en tant qu'utilisateur : NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Utilitaire d'exécution de package Microsoft (R) SQL Server  Version 11.0.5058.0 for 64-bit
  >   Échec de l'exécution du package serveur IS en raison de l'erreur 0x80131904. Serveur : OPP41****** Chemin du package : \SSISDB\automates\automate_PIT_pilotage\recuperation_cmd_a_traiter.dtsx
  >   ID de référence environnementale : NULL.  Description : Échec de la connexion. La connexion provient d'un domaine non approuvé et ne peut pas être utilisée avec l'authentification Windows.  Source : .Net SqlClient Data Provider

The owner of the job is my AD account.

This is how the step is configured : https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrJf9.png

The SQL Server Agent service is running through the "NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT" account.

Thank you very much by advance, I'm going crazy !

Answer (score 0):

1. Create credentials: Security -> Credentials
2. Create a proxy account: SQL Server Agent -> Proxies -> SSIS Package Execution
3. Set SSIS package to run as proxy account.

Take a look at [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/).

Answer (score 0):

I had found that my Job was executing against a DNS name and not the SQL Server Name. So check your SQL server name : select @@servername and make sure you use this name in referring to the SQL server where the catalog is located and not some or other DNS name. I have found that it will also succeed using the DNS name to call the packaged from a different SQL server, but if the job runs on the local SQL server calling a package on the same SQL server then the server name must refer to the value in @@Servername.